# An algorithm to find isometry between surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

Given two surfaces in $R^3$, i would like to find isometry between these two. Usually, in class, we did some examples, like bending the plane into a cylinder, or cone, and they were not hard, quite trivial, actually. I was wondering whether a more general algorithm exists, that, presuming surfaces are isometric, gives us, at least one isometry map between them. I know that surface isometry preserves first fundamental form, and was i thinking that it might help in the process, but i can't figure out the whole general algorithm on a more abstract level,  and am only able to figure it out somehow, if i am given the surfaces already.

Comment: Why do you expect there should be such an algorithm? That seems like far too much to ask, even if you make severe restrictions on the surfaces involved.

Comment: Piecewise linear can probably be done with a reasonable algorithm.

Comment: If you know a pair of points p in the first surface and q in the second surface which should correspond as well as matching tangent directions, then you can write down the exponential map based at each and from those write down the whole isometry (as a composition of the exponential map of the first composed with the inverse of the exponential map of the second), at least inside the injectivity radius. So if you want to find an approximate isometry if such exists, you can iterate over a grid of points and discrete tangent directions at those points and integrate up the geodesics approximately.

Comment: This is a simple example of the problem of equivalence. A modern reference is the book [Exterior Differential Systems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461397168) by Bryant, Chern, Goldschmidt, and Griffiths. However, I'm guessing you don't have the background for this book. Differential forms give a very natural setting in which to look for a mapping from one surface to another with certain geometric properties.